# 'function' object has no attribute 'encode' error using AWS SES + Python SMTP

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, email, smtp, amazon-ses

I am trying to send an email using AWS SES from python smtp but I am receiving this error.

```
'function' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

the email sending looks like this

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

import common.config_constants as constants


class Email_util:

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.smtp_server = 'email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com'
        self.smtp_port = constants.SMTP_PORT
        self.workmail_user = constants.SMTP_USER
        self.workmail_pass = constants.SMTP_PASS
        self.sender = constants.FORGOT_PASSWORD_EMAIL_HANDLER
        pass

    def send_email(self, receiver, subject, body):
        msg = MIMEMultipart()
        msg['From'] = self.send_email
        msg['To'] = receiver
        msg['Subject'] = subject

        # Attach the email body
        msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))

        try:
            # Establish a connection to Amazon WorkMail SMTP server
            server = smtplib.SMTP(self.smtp_server, self.smtp_port)
            server.starttls()

            # Login to Amazon WorkMail
            server.login(self.workmail_user, self.workmail_pass)

            # Send the email
            server.sendmail(self.sender, receiver, msg.as_string())

            print("Email sent successfully!")
            return True
        except for Exception as e:
            print(f"Error sending email: {e}")
            return False
```

any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please add the full traceback, which would tell you exactly which `function` doesn't have an `encode` attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
    def send_email(self, receiver, subject, body):
        msg = MIMEMultipart()
        msg['From'] = self.send_email
```

You're putting the function `self.send_email` as the value for `msg['From']` here, this should be a string instead.
Strings in Python have a property called `encode`, which is actually a function used to convert it from one format into another (like, say 'UTF-8' to a byte array).

Hope that helps :)